# Enumerate Windows Paper Sizes

Tags: windows, delphi, locale

I can get the current Locale paper size using

```
GetLocaleStr(LCID,LOCALE_IPAPERSIZE,IntToStr(DMPAPER_A4))
```

where `LOCALE_IPAPERSIZE = $100A`

but is there a way to enumerate all paper sizes with their names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no enumerator, see [Paper Sizes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319099%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN for a full list.

You can find out paper sizes that a particular installed printer supports, but that wouldn't possibly include all.

Answer (score 1):

There is [`EnumForms`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162624%28VS.85%29.aspx).

[Stephen Friedl](http://www.unixwiz.net/tools/winforms.html) has done research on this subject.

Comment: This, however, enumerates *forms* for a *specific printer*.

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz, not really, visit the second link :)

Comment: Query the local print server.., good one! If association of paper size type constants (DMPAPER_..) and names in current locale is not required, I think this is the better answer.

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz, it is not possible to retrieve **constants** because spooler itself is not only forms' source (hence WinNLS does not know  at compile time), but rather localized display names directly (if any, `FORM_INFO_2.StringType <>  STRING_NONE`).