# How to get all paper size names and corresponding pixel dimensions?

Tags: delphi

I am writing a WYSIWYG page designer application, which will allow user to drop images and text onto a designer Panel and then print the panel to PDF.

In my application's Page Setup options, the user needs to select a page size, and then, based on selected page size it will show a panel on screen that is sized according to the dimensions (eg A4 selected = 8.5 x 11 inches and Panel will be sized to these pixel dimensions) .

Then when user clicks Print, the contents of the Panel will be drawn to a PDF file with the selected dimensions.

I am using the wPDF component set, and the TWPPDFPrinter component in particular to create the PDF.

My question:

1. How to get list of all paper sizes names, and then how to get their corresponding dimensions for wPDFPrinter ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please define precisely what you mean by "all paper sizes"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the list of all the printer forms defined in a system:

```
uses
  winspool, printers;

...


procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  HPrinter: THandle;
  Forms: array of TFormInfo1;
  Count, Needed, Returned: DWORD;
  i: Integer;
begin
  Memo1.Clear;
  if OpenPrinter(nil, HPrinter, nil) then begin
    try
      if not EnumForms(HPrinter, 1, nil, 0, Needed, Returned) then begin

        // we should fail here since we didn't pass a buffer
        if GetLastError <> ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER then
          RaiseLastOSError;

        Count := (Needed div SizeOf(TFormInfo1)) + 1;
        SetLength(Forms, Count);
        if EnumForms(HPrinter, 1, @Forms[0], SizeOf(TFormInfo1) * Count, Needed,
            Returned) then begin
          if Returned < Count then
            SetLength(Forms, Returned);
          for i := 0 to Returned - 1 do begin
             Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Paper name: %s,   Paper size: %dmm x %dmm',
                            [Forms[i].pName,
                             Forms[i].Size.cx div 1000,
                             Forms[i].Size.cy div 1000]))
          end;
        end else
          RaiseLastOSError;
      end;
    finally
      ClosePrinter(HPrinter);
    end;
  end else
    RaiseLastOSError;
end;
```

Comment: Thx for the answer. But the first thing is that TWPPDFPrinter is a component, so how do I select this as the printer index?

Comment: @Steve - I thought it was a printer... Anyway, you'd either get the list of all forms defined in the spooler, or get the list of forms supported by a specific printer. For the former pass 'nil' as the first parameter of `OpenPrinter`, for the latter you should pass a printer name as the first parameter of 'OpenPrinter'. (Of course it is in fact not exactly necessary to select the printer, just pass a 'nil' or a valid 'printer name' to OpenPrinter).

Comment: OTOH it doesn't seem to make a difference. See the note [on this page](http://www.berezniker.com/content/pages/visual-foxpro/enumerating-printer-forms), which I can verify here and there are threads on the net amounting to the same. In short, if you want to get the list that a specific printer supports do not use 'EnumForms', use 'DeviceCapabilities'.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a list of paper sizes using EnumForms and Querying the local print server.  see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679413/enumerate-windows-paper-sizes)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the default printer setup dialog?

Link the following handler to the `OnAccept` event of a `TFilePrintSetup` action:

```
procedure TForm1.FilePrintSetup1Accept(Sender: TObject);
var
  Scale: Single;
begin
  Scale := Printer.PageHeight / Printer.PageWidth;
  DesignerPanel.Height := Round(DesignerPanel.Width * Scale);
end;
```

Ét voila.