# How to use DeviceCapabilities to Retrieve the paper names and sizes from specific printer in Delphi

Tags: delphi, winapi, printing, vcl

I have been looking for a way of retrieving the papers supported by an specific printer and their sizes (width and height) in millimeters if possible.

I have seen and "Studied" many posts and sites about using `Printer.Getprinter` and `Printer.SetPrinter` but I am really far from understanding the whole process to make that work, I learnt that I have to use `DeviceCapabilities` in order to retrieve data that is specific to one printer but I really don't know how to use those structures. I need something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122334/how-to-get-all-paper-size-names-and-corresponding-pixel-dimensions) but for a specific printer and using the `DeviceCapabilities`.
I use Delphi VCL.

In the question linked, they use `EnumForms` which I understand is for all the printers, they also mention that `DeviceCapabilities` is for a specific printer, and that is what I need, to get the supported paper names and sizes but only for the selected printer and not all of them.
lets say I select my printer: Printer.PrinterIndex:= `Printer.Printers.IndexOf(MyPrinter);` I would like to get the papers and paper sizes for those supported by that printer.

Thank you so much for any help provided!

Comment: Do you want to write code for an arbitrary printer, or just this Brother model?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The printer may change depending on the user, but the brother model is the one I am currently running tests.

Comment: Yes @whosrdaddy, that is actually the post I linked in my question. The thing is that Sertac said that if you want data from a specific printer you should use `DeviceCapabilities`  instead of `EnumForms`

Comment: You should remove reference to a specific printer to avoid anyone thinking you want code for that model specifically

Comment: Thanks @DavidHeffernan, I edited my question.

Comment: @whosrdaddy I tried the code, but It gives more papers than the current printer supports. in fact it doesn’t give me some papers that the printer actually supports.

Comment: Hi Hiram, I see. Please try out Peter Belows' code from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=de#!topic/borland.public.delphi.winapi/vKjwHUB96FI), more specific the `GetPaperInfo` procedure.

Comment: @whosrdaddy I will try it and let you know, thanks a lot for helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that calls `DeviceCapabilities` for the currently selected printer and outputs supported paper names for "the current default initialization values for the specified printer driver" to a memo. The quoted part in the previous sentence is from the [documentation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjbqMOt2aTkAhWvMewKHQ68Aj4QFjAAegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fwindows%2Fwin32%2Fapi%2Fwingdi%2Fnf-wingdi-devicecapabilitiesa&usg=AOvVaw3xDWEgVvPYJukAcg-OMKTE) of the function and I'm not absolutely positive that I understand what it means. That happens because a `DevMode` is not passed.

```delphi
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  PrinterName: string;
  HPrinter: THandle;
  Ret: DWORD;
  Buf: array of array [0..63] of Char;
  i: Integer;
begin
  PrinterName := Printer.Printers[Printer.PrinterIndex];
  if OpenPrinter(PChar(PrinterName), HPrinter, nil) then begin
    Ret := DeviceCapabilities(PChar(PrinterName), nil, DC_PAPERNAMES, nil, nil);
    if Ret > 0 then begin
      SetLength(Buf, Ret);
      DeviceCapabilities(PChar(PrinterName), nil, DC_PAPERNAMES, Pointer(Buf), nil);
      for i := 0 to Ret - 1 do
        Memo1.Lines.Add(Buf[i]);
    end;
    ClosePrinter(HPrinter);
  end;
end;
```

Explaining the code is kind of pointless, I'd be duplicating the documentation. I included the link above.

Comment: I tried the code but the memo fills with numbers instead of names and they go like this:  | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 3  | 3  | 5  | 5  | 6  | 6  | 6  | 1  | 2  | 5  | 1  | 2  | 3  | 5  | 5  | 6  | 1  | 2  | 3  | 5  | 5  | 6  | 1  |

I just changed the `PrinterName` to my printer, which does exist.

Comment: @Hiram the PAnsiChar cast should be PChar, in memo.lines.add. Still seems to be a problem though, I'll have a look.

Comment: thank you so much for taking the time. And yes,  I also got an Access Violation if I close the program after clicking the button.

Comment: @Hiram - I modified string extraction code, please try it again with the update.

Comment: It worked perfect! is it possible to use this code in a similar way to get the paper's width and height in millimeters?

Comment: Yes. Instead of a [0..63] char array, you need to pass a point array. And the appropriate flag of course - need to read DC_PAPERSIZE in docs. Please notify if you get stuck...

Comment: Alright, I will try that and let you know and then I'll mark it as the correct answer. you have truly helped me a lot, Thanks!

Comment: I think I got it. Only one last question, for papers like 62mm x 100mm when filling the memo I get 62 x 99, I am showing `Buf[i].X div 10;` and `Buf[I].Ydiv 10;` so that I get mm and not 10th of mm. do you see any problem if I round those numbers up so that they match the same value as the one the paper name says?

Comment: Yeah, how would you know if you have to round up a number or not. I think I'd use `Round(Buf[i].X/10)` or perhaps `Trunc(SizeBuf[i].X/10`

Comment: I'll do some tests with both. Thanks Sertac, you have helped me a lot with the problem and also understanding `DeviceCapabilities`.

Comment: The latter (trunc) is an error on my part, it would be identical with div. I don't understand how you can end up with 99 from (100# div 10). You're welcome.

Comment: the thing is that the point has a value of 998, and I do 998 div 10 and that is where I get the 99, I don't get the full 1000 from the point.Y. in other paper instead of getting Y 540 I get Y 539